Ways to make sure iOS app stays on in background
I am working on an iOS app that is connected to an ELD, which is a device that sends vehicle and gps data to a bluetooth connected phone. Basically my app works by connecting to it using bluetooth, and then parsing the packets that reach the phone every few seconds, and then creating logs from that data.
I currently have an issue with the app working in the background. I did enable background modes and the app does work in background most of the time, however the system sometimes kills it for some reason. Is there any way I can get the app to stay on as long as it's connected to the device, or maybe a way for the app to wake up if it's killed/suspended while in the background? Any ideas are appreciated? Thanks.

When you say you have enabled background modes, which specifically? (Do not just turn all of them on.) As a general rule, if you have Bluetooth connected and have a connection and your device is sending data every few seconds, your app should not be terminated. But you'll need to explain how you've configured it, and why you believe the OS is terminating your app rather than your app crashing due to a bug. Have you confirmed that you actually receiving data every few seconds, right up until the app is terminated? How did you determine that? Have you implemented Bluetooth state restoration?

I use a service called bugfender which I use to log data and events back to me so I can debug what is happening. I have background fetch, remote notifications, background processing, Uses bluetooth LE accessories, location updates and audio, airplay, and picture in icture enabled. I don't think the app is crashing because bugfender should catch the crash and then send a report back to me. The data should be constantly sent. I did not implement bluetooth state restoration or anything related to bluetooth as there is a prebuilt service that manages the bluetooth connection.

This service automatically directly connects to a device, and from what I can see it does not have bluetooth state restoration implemented. I am guessing that could be the issue. I determined that the data is being sent because the ELD device also sends packets to an online service via internet, where I can see all logs of previous packets sent to the device every few seconds. The app is working by getting the packets, saving them to a realm database, and sending that data via an api request if the app has internet. Could the app be killed because it is doing too much in the background?

"as there is a prebuilt service that manages the bluetooth connection." This sounds like you should direct your questions to the service. "background fetch, remote notifications, background processing, Uses bluetooth LE accessories, location updates and audio, airplay, and picture in icture enabled." Really, you are using picture-in-picture? Just throwing every entitlement you can imagine is not how things work, and can conflict. You need to request what you use, and request it properly. "Could the app be killed because it is doing too much in the background?" Yes, if you take too long.

Going to add I ended up fixing this. An issue was with my app entering deadlock in certain cases, causing the system to kill it. Thanks for your tips, they helped me come up with a solution.
